# ¿Como recuperar un dato de un Store Procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Estoy tratando de recuperar un valor de un SP que tengo creado, el cual me regresa un string como el que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi método donde ejecuto el SP, trate de recuperar el valor con
`SqlParameter return= new SqlParameter();` `return.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;` pero no obtuve el resultado que esperaba.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionIBCO))
                {
                    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

                    SqlParameter retorno = new SqlParameter();
                    retorno.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CK_stock", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",date);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
```

De que otra manera podría hacerlo? o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de usar

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

que se suele ejecutar cuando dentro del procedimiento va un update

usa

```
Valor = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Donde valor te recoge el valor que pongas el la **ultima** select del procedimiento almacenado:

```
Select Max(val) from TablaValores
```

entoces: Valor=Max(val)

Devuelve un máximo de 2033 caracteres con(en tu caso)

```
 ValorStr = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco, me funciono de maravilla.